# Rollback master origin without force push

Tags: git

Is there any way to rollback origin master to previous commit, if force push is disabled?
I have A -> B -> C
C is wrong commit, btw, B is a merge commit. I want master origin to go back to B, but force push is declined by server policies.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) C maybe ?

Comment: No. Not without write access to the server itself.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting into the technical options, we should recognize that a "no force push" policy means that you're not meant to be able to do what you describe.  Erasing commits from a ref's history is the crux of what "force push" does (above and beyond a regular push).  Generally there's good reason for an origin repo to reject force pushes - see "recovering form upstream rebase" section of the `git rebase` documentation, because even though you wouldn't be using the `rebase` command, the same situation applies.

And there are options that might be "good enough" in lieu of actually removing `C`; I'll come back to that.

But ok, let's suppose that for whatever reason you (and your team / repo owner / whoever is responsible for deciding if this is ok) understand the costs and still want to do this, but can't change the policy settings your server is enforcing.

***Is there another way to remove `C`***?

No simple one.  Not while treating the origin repo as a remote, anyway.  By definition "force push" is the operation that takes commits out of a remote ref's history.

**Option 1**: Well, I don't know how your origin repo is hosted.  Does the server software give you options for manipulating the repo?  If so that's your best bet.

**Option 2**: If you have direct access to the origin repo - if you can log in somewhere that allows you to treat it as a local repo - then you could do it.  The procedure is basically the same as how you did it locally, except you'd maybe have to create a work tree first (because typically the origin would be a bare repo).  Something like

```
git worktree add /path/to/create/a/worktree/at master
# cd into the new work tree
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Then remove the worktree (`rm -r ...`) and clean up (`git worktree prune`) so that git won't worry about pushes affecting the work tree.

**Option 3**: If you have direct access to the repo files but for some reason can't run git on them, you could in theory rewrite the ref itself.  Working directly on git files is a dangerous game and I don't really recommend it, but let nobody say I wasn't thorough in considering options.

Unless you know enough about git to figure this procedure out on your own, it's probably a bad idea to do it, so I'm moving on...

**Option 4**: I guess you could replace the entire repo.  We're really getting to the bottom of the barrel here.

***So what if I can't (or decide not to) remove `C`?***

You could `revert` it instead.  When you revert a commit `M`, that creates a new commit `W` that "undoes" whatever changes were done by creating `M`.  So

```
git revert C
```

would give you

```
      (origin/master)
            |
A --- B --- C --- !C <--(master)
     /
... X
```

where `!C` has the same `TREE` (content state) as `B`.  This can be pushed without `--force`.  Whether it's "good enough" depends.

If `C` contains sensitive data (passwords, keys), you might really want it out of history.  My advice is to change the passwords and revoke the keys.  (Even if you *were* to remove `C` from history, could you guarantee nobody had already copied it?)

If `C` contains large binary files... that's bad news.  The repo will always be burdened by the resulting bloat.  Replacing the repo with a rewritten history is the only real fix (and that takes us back to the above options).

But if it was just an "oops", then wanting it out of history is understandable but not necessary.  Individuals who don't want to see `C` in their history could consider using `git replace` to "paper over" the problem by 'replace'ing `!C` with `B` I guess, but it may not be worth it.  (Note that `replace` only creates the illusion of a change to history, and it has some documented quirks; anyone who decides to use it should read up on at least the basic documentation for the command.)